# Min/Max Width in IE6 without javascript?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, width, max, min

Is it possible to get min/max width working in IE6 without the use of javascript?

On a somewhat related note, does Google Chrome not understand,

```
<!--[if IE 6]><!-->
<!--<![endif]-->
```

or am I just screwing up that code. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

**First question**: no. You can sorta hack it using tables and images, but not in any way that approaches the ease of use of `max-`/`min-width`.

**Second question**: no - it sees them the same as every other non-IE browser, as comments. Perhaps you wanted:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
something IE6 should see
<![endif]-->
```

Note how the XML/HTML comment begins on the first line and doesn't end until the last.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's the 'downlevel revealed' conditional comment syntax. It validates, but there's not much use besides that. I suggest using the format Shog9 has listed.

Comment: That's downlevel hidden, actually, since it's hidden inside comments.

Comment: Actually, I see the extra comment syntax, which is not how you're supposed to do that.

Comment: That is how you downlevel-revealed whilst keeping valid/well-formed. The MS-recommended syntax without the extra comments is invalid. It's useful for tests like ‘if IE 8’ to supply the same code to standards-compliant browsers inluding IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're screwing that up. If you want downlevel revealed it should look like:

```
<![if IE 6]>
do something
<![endif]>
```

That will make the 'do something' code appear for IE 6, and all other non-IE browsers. IE 7, and IE 8 will not make whatever 'do something' is viewable.

Comment: Won't work - it must be a comment:
<!--[if IE 6]>something IE6 should see<![endif]-->
Let's check our answers before trying to help, mmmkay? :)

Comment: MaxVT, according to The Ultimate CSS Reference by SitePoint, apphacker has specified a syntax recommended by Microsoft - so you might apply your comment to your own comment.

Comment: It will work, and is MS's preferred code, but it's not valid markup. smith's version also works and is valid; it's just a bit odd to target (IE6 plus standards-compliant browsers)... presumbly he wanted a downlevel-hidden cc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution !!!
Before I start i must tell you dropdown select box will automatically expand in almost all the browsers except IE6.so.. i would do a browser check [ i.e., IE6] and write the following only to that browser.Here it goes..First check for the browser..

#### The code will magically expands the dropdown select box.The only problem with the solution is onmouseover the dropdown will be expanded to 420px.. and because the overflow = hidden we are hiding the expanded dropdown size and showing it as 170px;so, the arrow at the right side of the ddl will be hidden and cannot be seen. but the select box will be expanded to 420px;  which is what we really want. just try the below code for yourself and use it if you like it. Cheers.

.ctrDropDown
    {
        width:420px; 
    }
    .ctrDropDownClick
    {
        width:420px; 
    }

the above is the IE6 css. the common css [for all other browsers] should be as below.

```
    .ctrDropDown
{
    width:170px; <%--this is the actual width of the dropdown list--%>
}
.ctrDropDownClick
{
    width:auto; <%-- this the width of the dropdown select box.--%>
}
```